# Pull to refresh container

Tags: codenameone

I have a Picker with a button and `InfiniteContainer cnt` below it.
I make this container not scrollable `cnt.setScrollableY(false);` because I want the whole form stay scrollable. If my container contains a lot of items (more than initial display can show) and I leave my container scrollable it results in having two different scrollbars and it's confusing.
However, if I set the container to not scrollable, I can't implement `pullToRefresh()`.

I don't want to refresh my whole form, I want just to refresh this container. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pull to refresh must be scrollable as it ties directly into the dynamic fetching of additional elements.

You need to make the form non-scrollable and ideally use `BorderLayout` as the layout. If you do that make sure to place the infinite container in the center of the form.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it with `BorderLayout`. Before, if I make the form non-scrollable and my container is longer than a display height, I couldn't scroll it down.